# Using django with sqlite on aws lambda

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, sqlite, aws-lambda, zappa

I am trying to deploy my django app on aws lambda using zappa. However, when I try to login to the app I get `attempt to write a readonly database`.

My understanding is that this is because sqlite is an embedded database and you can't use embedded databases on lambda because they require write-access which is not possible on lambda and just generally not a good idea to try and persist data on lambda.

Is this correct? Is my only option to thus switch to using postgres or mysql or another server database?

Comment: Lambda has writable diskspace in /tmp but there's no guarantee that it will persist from one Lambda invocation to the next. It's also not shared across concurrently executing Lambda functions. You should store state outside of Lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need permanent storage, then yes, some flavor of RDS or Dynamodb or any other datastore you have access to would be more appropriate. Lambda by itself can't persist data between executions.